# How to enable/disable a member function according to the existence of a member of its derived class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

I had searched over 10 answers and nothing fits my current situation.

(member detector marcos comes from: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Member_Detector)

```
CREATE_MEMBER_DETECTOR(normal);
CREATE_MEMBER_DETECTOR(abnormal);

template <typename T>
struct Weapon
{
    //template <std::enable_if_t<Detect_normal<T>::value, T>* = nullptr>
    template <std::enable_if_t<Detect_abnormal<T>::value, bool> = true>
    void DefaultShoot()
    {
        std::cout << "special\n";
    }

    template <std::enable_if_t<Detect_normal<T>::value, bool> = true>
    void DefaultShoot()
    {
        std::cout << "general\n";
    }
};

struct FOO : public Weapon<FOO>
{
    static constexpr auto normal = 10;

    virtual void Shoot() { DefaultShoot(); }
};
```

Expect: The template generates a set of functions according to what constexpr I have in my subclasses.
Reality: Generate a bunch of errors and never successfully compiled...

Did anyone have a clue whether doing this in C++17 is possible?

Edit: Does the "else" possible in my situation?
This is actually my original intention.

```
template <typename T>
struct Weapon
{
    template <std::enable_if_t<Detect_abnormal<T>::value, bool> = true>
    void DefaultShoot()
    {
        std::cout << "special\n";
    }

    //template <std::enable_if_t<Detect_normal<T>::value, bool> = true>
    #some magical "else" code if the one above is invalidated.
    void DefaultShoot()
    {
        std::cout << "general\n";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need the template parameter from the method for SFINAE:

```
template <typename T>
struct Weapon
{
    template <typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<Detect_abnormal<U>::value, bool> = true>
    void DefaultShoot()
    {
        std::cout << "special\n";
    }

    template <typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<Detect_normal<U>::value, bool> = true>
    void DefaultShoot()
    {
        std::cout << "general\n";
    }
};
```

Notice that you will have ambiguous call if both are true at the same time.

As you are in C++17, you might use `if constexpr`:

```
template <typename T>
struct Weapon
{
    void DefaultShoot()
    {
        if constexpr (Detect_abnormal<T>::value) {
            std::cout << "special\n";
        } else if constexpr (Detect_normal<T>::value) {
            std::cout << "general\n";
        } // else {}
    }
};
```

C++20 would allow to use class template parameter in its `requires`:

```
template <typename T>
struct Weapon
{
    void DefaultShoot() requires(Detect_abnormal<T>::value)
    {
        std::cout << "special\n";
    }

    void DefaultShoot() requires(Detect_normal<T>::value)
    {
        std::cout << "general\n";
    }
};
```

Notice that you will have ambiguous call if both are true at the same time.

Comment: Thank you! But is it possible to create a "default" function if all special templates are invalidated?

Comment: See `if constexpr` way which should be the best fit.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that the existence of "if constexpr". But in my real code not the simplified one, the two function actually includes a bunch different stuff, and the existence of NORMAL static member is just a master switch. Will it work if my "if constexpr" followed by referring a bunch of non-existing member in its parantheses when the "else" case is true?

Comment: Condition of `if constexpr` should be known at compile time. "Wrong" branches are "discarded", so can have non-existing **dependent** members (mostly as template code). So it should be OK.

Answer (score 3):

Just for information, you can use simpler detector with C++17:

```
#define CREATE_MEMBER_DETECTOR(X) \
    template <typename T, typename = void> \
    struct Detect_ ## X : std::false_type {}; \
\
    template <typename T>\
    struct Detect_ ## X<T, std::void_t<decltype(T::X)> > \
        : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: Thank you for the update! Is there any newer textbook or explanation for these?

Comment: I don't know about books, but more info, and examples, available here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t